# Changing the height of just one of several select2 containers

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'm trying to increase the height of a select2 dropdown container while leaving  the other containers at the default height.  My container widths are fixed and I don't want a blank line forced into the container when I choose a second option (this would happen if I used 'height-min').  You'll [see all this in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbg7cvvy/)

Anyone any ideas on how I can control the first container while leaving the 2nd and 3rd containers alone?  Several posts on this already but nothing seems to work.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css


<select id="dropList1" style="width:125px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
  <option value="Moon">Moon</option>
  <option value="Stars">Stars</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropList2" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
  <option value="Wind">Wind</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropList3" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
  <option value="Water">Water</option>
</select>




$("#dropList1").select2({ placeholder: "Select type",});
$("#dropList2").select2({ placeholder: "Select type",});
$("#dropList3").select2({ placeholder: "Select type",});



body {
padding: 30px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
font-family: 'Arial', Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, using suggestions from other posts, but it simply had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the height by adding this to your css code

```
#dropList1 + .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{
  height: 100px;
}
```

> note that the height will be fixed

but if you want it to be increased automatically according to the element inside you need to use auto instead

```
#dropList1 + .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{
  height: auto;
}
```

and this will only affect the first select with ID = **#dropList1**

you can also decrease the space between the selected options in the input field to avoid the unnecessary line break by adding this code:

```
#dropList1 + .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{
      margin-right: 1px;
}
```

[**See JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbg7cvvy/3/)

Comment: Almost there, but that still allows a blank line to be forced into the container when just 2 options are selected

Comment: That depends on the size of the selected options.. if you select two short options the blank don't happen ... but you select even one large option it will happen and that's causing by the fixed width

Comment: In my original fiddle you'll see that I was able to put 'sun and 'moon' together without forcing a new line

Comment: @Silverburch thats how input field with multiple line behave .... i added a code to my answer that may help your problem

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I'm going to award @Chiller with the correct answer as this got closest to what I wanted and didn't need an additional plug-in

Comment: what about changing the height of the popup ?? who even wants to set the height of a select ffs..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a custom class to the required select tag and include the height you want in the css. Here's the below code:

```css
body {
padding: 30px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
font-family: 'Arial', Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
height: 27px;
}
.ChangedHeight{
height: 200px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css


<select id="dropList1" style="width:125px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
  <option value="Moon">Moon</option>
  <option value="Stars">Stars</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropList2" class="ChangedHeight" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
  <option value="Wind">Wind</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropList3" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
  <option value="Water">Water</option>
</select>
```

You can even add inline style in the select tag.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work because of the jquery plugin you suggested, but not sure why the display of the containers has gone a little crazy.

Answer (score 0):

For overwriting the first `Select` tag, use the shown `CSS code`

There is a pattern used by `SELECT2` plugin for creating the `HTML` for custom `SELECT` tag. So, by using the same pattern, you can overwrite your desired `SELECT2` tag.

```js
$("#dropList1").select2({
  placeholder: "Select type",
});
$("#dropList2").select2({
  placeholder: "Select type",
});
$("#dropList3").select2({
  placeholder: "Select type",
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
  font-family: 'Arial', Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 27px;
}

#dropList1+.select2 .select2-selection--multiple {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<h3>Managing the wrapper height to collect all selected tags properly</h3>
<select id="dropList1" class="select-one" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
  <option value="Moon">Moon</option>
  <option value="Stars">Stars</option>  
</select>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Default behaviour of the SELECT tag, the tags flow out of wrapper.</h3>

<select id="dropList2" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
  <option value="Wind">Wind</option>
  <option value="Moon">Moon</option>
  <option value="Stars">Stars</option>  
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropList3" style="width:125px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
  <option value="Water">Water</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Silverburch I thought you wanted to manage the height of first to other two. Apologies. Check the answer now. ! You can target it via `class` as well, I am controlling the `css` using `ID` of your desired `SELECT` tag.